# Default rails id column name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna rename the column `id`, how do I do?

I want to set `number` to primary key and auto increment, and `id` to just string of user id.

How do I do?

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user

      t.timestamps
    end

    rename_column :users, :id, :number
  end
end
```

I did like above, but it didn't work.

Comment: `it didn't work` means?

Comment: umm, there are id field and number field and id field is still primary key.

Comment: I advise you not to do this. Not using an ID or having a different name for that column results in a lot of long-term pain when using rails. Also, changing conventions basically defeats the purpose of having an opinionated framework with the convention over configuration approach.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I wouldn't recommend it, here is how I guess you can do it:

in your migration:

```
def up
  create_table :users, id: false do |t|
    t.string :user
    t.integer :number, null: false, index: true, unique: true
    t.timestamps
  end
  execute %Q{ ALTER TABLE "users" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("number"); }
end

def down
  drop_table :users
end
```

in your model:

```
self.primay_key = 'number'
```